# Excel file generated with EPPlus. Filters not working properly

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

First of all if this is the wrong place to ask this question, let me know.

Now I'll get right into it as clear as I can.

I generate and Excel file using EPPlus, from a C# application.

The file generates ok, but while using filters on it (not the ones from EPPlus, but from Excel itself) it dose not filter everything. It filters a few rows.

I can provide code snippets, or the excel generated file. I have searched the web a lot before coming here, but I have not found this problem encountered by someone else.

Thank you in advance for your input.

```
enter code here
        ExcelPackage ExcelPkg = new ExcelPackage();
        ExcelWorksheet wsSheet1 = ExcelPkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

            #region Create table and headers
            using (ExcelRange Rng = wsSheet1.Cells[TableRange])
            {
                //Create Table
                ExcelTable table = wsSheet1.Tables.Add(Rng, "OSTable");
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.Count; i++)
                {
                    table.Columns[i].Name = headers[i];
                }

                table.ShowHeader = true;
                table.ShowFilter = false; 
            }
            #endregion
```

#region Insert data into the Excel Table Cells

```
            foreach (ArticleRow ar in mainArticleList)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < ar.Qty.Count; i++)
                {
                    currentRow++;
                    string thisRowRange = "A" + currentRow.ToString() + ":" + "Q" + currentRow.ToString();


                    #region BOM_Position Col: A
                    using (ExcelRange Rng = wsSheet1.Cells["A" + currentRow.ToString()])
                    {
                        Rng.Value = Convert.ToInt32(ar.BOM_Position);
                        Rng.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                        Rng.Style.Font.Size = FontSize;
                    }
                    #endregion
                    #region Input Col: B
                    using (ExcelRange Rng = wsSheet1.Cells["B" + currentRow.ToString()])
                    {
                        Rng.Value = ar.Input;
                        Rng.Style.Font.Size = FontSize;
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region QTY Col: J
                    using (ExcelRange Rng = wsSheet1.Cells["J" + currentRow.ToString()])
                    {
                        Rng.Value = ar.Qty[i];
                        Rng.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                        Rng.Style.Font.Size = FontSize;

                    }
                    #endregion
                    #endregion
                    #region Price Col: L
                    using (ExcelRange Rng = wsSheet1.Cells["L" + currentRow.ToString()])
                    {
                        Rng.Value = ar.Price[i];
                        Rng.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                        Rng.Style.Font.Size = FontSize;
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #endregion
                    #region ArticleUrl Col: Q
                    using (ExcelRange Rng = wsSheet1.Cells["Q" + currentRow.ToString()])
                    {
                        Rng.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(\"" + ar.Link + "\", \"" + ar.Store + "\")";
                        Rng.StyleName = StyleName;
                        Rng.Style.Font.Size = FontSize;
                    }
                    #endregion


                    #region  Formatting Row Color by Store 
                    using (ExcelRange Rng = wsSheet1.Cells[thisRowRange])
                    {


                        Rng.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.None;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.None;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Left.Color.SetColor(Color.LightCyan);
                        Rng.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        Rng.Style.Border.Right.Color.SetColor(Color.LightCyan);

                        Rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;

                        if (ar.Store == "Farnell" | ar.Store == "FarnellBETA")
                        { Rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(ColorFarnellRow); }
                        else if (ar.Store == "Mouser")
                        { Rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(ColorMouserRow); }

                    }
                    #endregion


                    #region Formatting Stock Cell Color by Content
                    using (ExcelRange Rng = wsSheet1.Cells["I" + currentRow.ToString()])
                    {
                        if (ar.Stock == "0" | ar.Stock == "-" | ar.Stock == "n/a" | ar.Stock == "--")
                        {
                            Rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                            Rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Red);
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion

                }
            }
            #endregion
```

I have deleted some repetitive parts of the code, as to not clutter you.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try **TableStyle: OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium6** , this is part of EpPlus. and you can apply this with header.The **tab style** gives good UI looks(BackgroundColor) as well as auto filter.

Anyway you are writing so many additional code for Style, then you are filtering as well(which is not working for you).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will look into what you said. This is my first time using EPPlus, and I didn't exactly knew the right way. I've learned of it from a youtube tutorial and I tought this is how it's suppose to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the source of my problem , and I've decided to post an answer maybe it will help someone in the future.

I had given a wrong Table Range, making my table smaller than all the data I was writing, and the rest of the data was written outside the table. That's why I could not filter. The filters were working but only on a part of the table.